# How to fix: TypeError: lmplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to plot with seaborn.

Using:

```
df=pd.read_csv("breast-cancer.data.txt",na_values=['?'])
df.drop(["id"],axis=1,inplace=True)
df["label"].replace(2,0,inplace=True)
df["label"].replace(4,1,inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

full_data=df.astype(float).values.tolist()
df.head()

for i in range(1,10):
    sns.lmplot(str('x'+str(i)), 'label', data=df, fit_reg=False)
```

Gives me an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 2
      1 for i in range(1,10):
----> 2     sns.lmplot(str('x'+str(i)), 'label', data=df, fit_reg=False)

TypeError: lmplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'
```

How do I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you describe the content of "df"?

Comment: df is for breast cancer data

Comment: Please consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what he means by describe is tell us some sample of the data (column and some rows), you can tell us the dummy data not the real one

Comment: The first parameter to `.lmplot()` is `data`.  So you're implicitly passing `str('x'+str(i))` for that parameter, and also explicitly passing `data=df` later on in the parameter list.  I'm not sure what parameter `str('x'+str(i))` was supposed to be, but you probably just need to give an explicit keyword to specify it.  (Same for the `'label'` parameter.)

Comment: Reopening this. It's the same root case as the  question it was marked as a duplicate of, but the error message is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to [`lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) is `data`.

In this call, the third argument is also `data`:

```
sns.lmplot(str('x'+str(i)), 'label', data=df, fit_reg=False)
```

So, `data` is given twice, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
sns.lmplot(x = str('x' + str(i)), y = 'label', data = df, fit_reg = False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
sns.lmplot(x = 'x-axis', y = 'y-axis', data = 'your-data');
```

please try to give both x, y-axis and this should probably solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer solved my problem. In the doc (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) The data comes first and is followed by axis information. The arguments order are different than the doc so python needs to know what is what.